# How to change the sequence of attributes when creating a tag?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, tags, emmet

When creating a tag, I need the attribute class to always be the first.
If i create a tag like: a.link the result is this `<a href="" class="link"></a>`
or img.header__img `<img src="" alt="" class="header__img">`, how i can change sequence? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**, vscode is adding the ability to reverse attributes through an emmet setting, see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/110251 (Implement output.reverseAttributes for emmet snippets).

It is in the Insiders' Build v1.54.  In your `settings.json`:

```
  "emmet.preferences": {
    "output.reverseAttributes": true
  }
```

Tested in Insider's Build and it is working as you wanted.  Notes that in the `img.header_img` case the result is

```
<img class="header__img" src="" alt="">
```

so the `class` is first.  I'm not sure that is *technically reversed* as the `src` is now the second attribute not the third.  But I think you just wanted the `class` first and the it is fine if the `src` is second or third.

---

Previous answer:

I have a partial answer, maybe someone has something better.  See [custom emmet snippets in vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet#_using-custom-emmet-snippets).

Create a snippets.json file.

Use this setting to point to your snippets.json directory (not the file itself):

```
"emmet.extensionsPath": "C:\\Users\\Mark\\OneDrive\\Test Bed\\.vscode",
```

In a snippets.json file put something like this:

```
{
  "html": {
      "snippets": {
          "iq": "<img src='${1}' alt='${2}' class='${3}'>",
          "aq": "<a class='${1}' href='${2}'></a>"
      }
  },
  "css": {
      "snippets": {
          "cb": "color: blue",
          "bsd": "border: 1px solid ${1:red}",
          "ls": "list-style: ${1}"
      }
  }
}
```

You see that <kbd>iq</kbd> and <kbd>aq</kbd> will now trigger `img` and `a` tags with the attribute order you wish.

However, you cannot simply do a <kbd>aq.someClass</kbd> and have it populate the class attribute.  It doesn't work.  Perhaps someone knows how to make that work or to simply override the built-in emmet snippets.